# TextField in StatelessWidget returning null when printed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to print **newTaskTitle** that is, text retrieved from the text field. This is a stateless widget.
But when the on pressed is triggered *null* is getting printed.
Also printing *value* is correctly printing the typed text.

```
class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  String newTaskTitle; 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Add Task',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                fontSize: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (value) {
                newTaskTitle = value;
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text(
                'Add',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                print(newTaskTitle); //This printing null...
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the output in Android Studio

````
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11205): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11205): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11205): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11205): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11205): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11205): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11205): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11205): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11205): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
I/flutter (11205): null```
````

Comment: Have you tried using a `TextEditingController` or do you specifically need it stored in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
>
> void main() => runApp(MyApp());
>
> class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return MaterialApp(
>       title: 'Hello You',
>       theme: ThemeData(
>         primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
>       ),
>       home: new HelloYou(),
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> class HelloYou extends StatefulWidget {
>   @override
>   State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HelloYouState();
> }
>
> class _HelloYouState extends State<HelloYou> {
>
>   String newTaskTitle = "";
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>       appBar: AppBar(
>         title: Text("HelloYou App !"),
>         backgroundColor: Colors.green,
>       ),
>       body: Container(
>           padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
>           child: Column(
>             children: <Widget>[
>               TextField(
>                 onChanged: (str) {
>                   setState(() {
>                     newTaskTitle = str;
>                   });
>                 },
>               ),
>               FlatButton(
>               child: Text(
>                 'Add',
>                 style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
>               ),
>               color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
>               onPressed: () {
>                 print(newTaskTitle);
>               },
>             )
>
>             ],
>           )),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Please check my code. You can use `StatefulWidget`

Answer (score 0):

Use a TextEditingController:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: _textEditingController,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => print(_textEditingController.text),
          child: Text("Press Me"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```